# C# 4 vs ActionScript 3: syntax differences

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, syntax

Look, before I get comments about how stupid I am for asking a question like this, I'd like it to be extremely clear that I understand that these two languages are vastly different. However, the way the languages are written happen to be quite similar.

I'm a heavy ActionScripter who has entered a .NET environment. What are the written syntax differences between the two? I'd like to use useful to the .NET team beyond my plug-in island.

example:

```
// AS   
private function SendMail():void {
    //do something
}

//C#
static void SendMail() {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a pretty vast question... Wouldn't it be easier to ask for a good reference book on C#?

Comment: Maybe... but unless there's a "C# to AS3: The Reference Guide", it doesn't really help me. I might as well just read a C# book.

Comment: That was my point! Since you already know AS3 , you should be able to highlight the differences yourself by reading about C#. I doubt that a few answers here can cover the subject...

Comment: No doubt... but I need to be aware of glaring differences ASAP since it's now a part of my job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already seen the largest difference yourself: declarations in ActionScript are

```
[protection specifier] (function | var) name : type;
```

and in C# are

```
[protection specifier] type name;
```

"static" is nearly the same between Actionscript and C#; the equivalent to your AS function header would be

```
private void SendMail() {}
```

in C#.

The other most-visible difference, for me at least, is Object() and Array(), which are actual, you know, TYPES in C#, but are more sort of squishy throw-in-whatever-you-want things in AS. Or so it feels like to me-- I've just spent the last few weeks doing the exact opposite thing from what you're talking about, going from C# to Actionscript :).

Comment: Interesting. Anything else I need to be aware of? And how are you liking AS3 thus far?

Comment: I think it's better to call it `modifier`

Answer (score 3):

This is also a difference: In Actionscript 3, getters/setters are functions, in C# you define them inside the variable.

**C#**

```
    private string _Description;

    public string Description
    {
        get { return _Description; }
        set { _Description = value; }
    }
```

**AS3**

```
private var _description:String;

public function get description():String 
{ 
    return _description; 
}

public function set description(value:String):void 
{
    _description = value;
}
```

Comment: This is something really nice about AS3, makes factoring a breeze.